# Asp.net IDentity 2 Database First AspNetUserLogins' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using database first approach with asp.net identity 2.

Now in my asp.net mvc project I have two datacontext one for the identity and other for my exist database.

I have a table in my exist database called Client and I wan't to create one to many relation with AspNetUsers.

I do it like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And this is my Myappcontext

```
public partial class Myappcontext: DbContext
{
    public Myappcontext()
        : base("name=Myappcontext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<products> products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagrams> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application and enter my email and password to connect I get this error

```
 EntityType 'AspNetUserLogins' has no key defined. Define the key for     this EntityType.
AspNetUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins' is based on type 'AspNetUserLogins' that has no keys defined.
```

I don't now how i fix this problem because I didn't found a guide how to create relation when we use database first and identity 2.

And I'm sorry about my bad language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of searching i didn't find any solutions for my probleme because i'm beginer in asp.net identity and ef6 i decide to create one DbContext for put identity and my database and using code first to recreate my database like this :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext,Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

i don't know if this is the best method to work but i have no choice until now